# Resumindo o resultado de vários testes lógicos em um único resultado

Tags: java, android

Boa tarde,

Tenho algumas strings que são oriundas de testes.
Exemplo:

```
            String teste2 = (nB < 0.0 && m1 <= j ? "OK" : "Não passa!");
            String teste3 = (nB < 0.0 && m2 <= j ? "OK" : "Não passa!");
            String teste4 = (nB > 0.0 && m2 <= 35.0 ? "OK" : "Não passa!");
            String teste5 = (nB > 0.0 && m2 <= 35.0 ? "OK" : "Não passa!");
```

Gostaria de resumir tudo em uma única string. No caso, se algum dos testes mostrasse a mensagem "Não passa!" a minha string resumo retornaria "Não passa!", caso contrário, ela retornaria "OK". O problema é que com o código a seguir ela sempre retorna "Não passa!".

```
String resultado = (teste2.equals("Não passa!") || teste3.equals("Não passa!") || teste4.equals("Não passa!") || teste5.equals("Não passa!") || teste6.equals("Não passa!") || teste7.equals("Não passa!") || teste8.equals("Não passa!") || teste9.equals("Não passa!") || teste10.equals("Não passa!") ? "Não passa!" : "OK");
```

O que estou fazendo errado?
Grato.

Comment: No `teste4`, não era para usar `m1` ao invés de `m2`?

Comment: Isso nunca vai passar, pois o `nb < 0.0` do `teste1` e `teste2` contraria o `nb > 0.0` do `teste3` e `teste4`.

Comment: Porque você usa `String`s com `"OK"` e `"Não passa!"` junto com o operador ternário e depois sai fazendo testes com `equals` ao invés de simplesmente usar o `boolean` diretamente?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
        boolean teste2 = nB < 0.0 && m1 <= j;
        boolean teste3 = nB < 0.0 && m2 <= j;
        boolean teste4 = nB > 0.0 && m1 <= 35.0;
        boolean teste5 = nB > 0.0 && m2 <= 35.0;

        // ...

        boolean resultado = teste2 && teste3 && teste4 && teste5
                && teste6 && teste7 && teste8 && teste9 && teste10;
```

Evite usar [programação orientada a strings](http://desciclopedia.org/wiki/Gambi_Design_Patterns#Programa.C3.A7.C3.A3o_Orientada_a_Strings). Isso é uma péssima prática de programação.

Além disso, note que a condição `nb < 0.0` do `teste2` e do `teste3` e a codição `nb > 0.0` do `teste4` e do `teste5`. Não há como essas duas condições serem verdadeiras simultaneamente porque `nb` não pode ser maior e menor que zero ao mesmo tempo. Logo, não há como o `resultado` ser verdadeiro.

Assim sendo, ou alguns desses seus testes devem estar verificando condições incorretas ou então há algum furo na lógica daquilo que você está testando.